# Visual Basic Not all code paths return a value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Basic 2010, my program compiles without any problem. However, I get a warning "Not all code paths return a value" on function. Since our assignment requirement must submit without any error and **warning** so i need to solve these error.

Part of my sample code:

```
Dim i as integer = 0 
Dim currentChar as string = frmMyCompiler.textbox.text(i)

Function toNextWord() 
    i = i + 1 
    currentChar = frmMyCompiler.textbox.text(i)
end Function
```

My function did not have any data type because it no need to return anything.
Can VB use *Void* same as C++ ?? Anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Check that you have Option Strict On.  That code should not even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sub toNextWord()` to return void, instead of `Function`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx) you have documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Functions should always a return a value. As your using Function toNextWord () it has no return value.

[Difference between Method and Function](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20f292bb-8d8c-4f1e-9ddc-28d68955a418/difference-between-method-vs-function)